# No overload matches this call. angular2 to angular12

Tags: angular, typescript, upgrade, angular2-template, angular12

[image: I am getting error in JSON.springify after I changed Headers to HttpHeaders because I upgraded my angular from Angular-2 to Angular-12]

[image: This is the error I am getting.Can anyone tell me what to use instead of JSON.stringify of maybe there is some fix in it .Kindly help.I am stuck here!]

I am upgrading my Angular-2 project to Angular-12 project and when I changed :

Before

**import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';**

After

**import { HttpClient, HttpResponse, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';**

I am facing issue to use HttpHeaders in place of Headers
You can see the images below. I am stuck here. Need some help.

Comment: Are you trying to update directly from 2 to 12?

Comment: No,but I am changing 
import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
TO
import { HttpClient, HttpResponse, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
in angular 12

Comment: @HarunYilmaz can you tell me what to use instead of  body: JSON.stringify(dataObject)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you set `body` in a `GET` request which has no body!

You can use this code below, **but you will have to change your backend to use** `queryParams`:

```
 this.http.get('myurl', { params: dataObject })
```

Comment: What is the correct thing to use ?

Comment: Well it depends on the request, if you still want to use GET you should send it over query params (those that come after the '?')

Comment: Check out this URL: https://assertible.com/blog/7-http-methods-every-web-developer-should-know-and-how-to-test-them

Comment: I am a junior developer ,Can you please write it for me ,it will be really appreciated

Comment: I have edited the answer for you

Comment: Great! you can accept this answer by clicking on the tick below the score

Comment: Is there any other way in which we don't change backend code?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm not sure even if the body that has been used here is really sent with the request. Try testing it yourself